# MongoDB & Mongoose: Can mongoose map referenced documents before referenced document is created?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I think my post title is a bit nebulous. Let me clarify.

I have the following schemas:

```
   var listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            _owner: { type:ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            title: String,
            description: String,
            creation_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        });


        var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            _taskList:   { type: ObjectId, ref: 'List' },
            title: String,
            description: String,
            creation_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        });

    var List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);
    var Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

Each 'Task' references a 'List'. Is it possible to save a new 'Task' referencing a 'List' that does not already exist in the collection? For example:

```
 //assume I have a user.id 

    var NewList = new List({
                    _owner: user._id,
                    title: 'Test List',
                    description: 'List Description'
                });

    var NewTask = new Task({
                    _taskList : NewList, //ref to the document above (_id not created yet)
                    title: 'Task Title',
                    description: 'Task Description'

                });

   NewTask.save(function(err, task){
                ...
               });
```

Is something like this possible or do I need to save the List then save the Task?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It definitely is possible. You can just set IDs manually. But do you see a problem with this approach? What if `NewList.save` fails after `NewTask.save` completes? Well, consistency is a general problem with Mongo anyway...

Comment: @freakish sure. I would be assuming that if the referenced document save() failed then neither document would be saved. That's the transactional behavior you would expect using a RDBMS ORM in another environment. So as far as you know it is necessary to perform two save transactions (given my example)? That's fine. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose actually creates the `_id` value for a new doc client-side, so you have access to the `_id` for `NewList` even before you save it.

So you can simply do:

```
var NewTask = new Task({
                _taskList : NewList._id, 
                title: 'Task Title',
                description: 'Task Description'
            });
```